# inverse of even number of elements in a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

if an abelian group with |G|=n where n is odd. if i take out the identity i'm left with even # of distinct elements. can this mean that each element has an inverse which is not itself??
not a homework question!
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a group of odd order, no element is its own inverse, since that would yield a subgroup of order $2$, and the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

Comment: D'oh. I used a super-cannon to shoot this little bird.

Comment: @Hagen: :-) Well, it's always good to have super-cannons at your disposal, and if you practice your aim on little birds once in a while, you don't get out of practice in case you ever do need that super-cannon :-)

Comment: ohh God that didnt cross my mind!! thanx a ton joriki!! :))

Answer (score 1):

By the classification theorem of finite abelian groups, $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups. If $n$ is odd, each cyclic summand must be odd and odd cyclic groups have no involutions apart from 1. Hence you are right.

Comment: thnx a lot!! i havent yet taken anything about direct sum of cyclic groups yet. but i will surely keep this in mind.